# Authenticate all urls except whitelist

Tags: django, django-views

Currently I wrote a method which authenticates a user using my company list of groups by getting the user using

```
request.meta['REMOTE_USER']
```

and comparing it to list of users in the group
My question is that how would I tie this in to my Django application such that it would check the users only for all urls except for a whitelist. I was thinking of calling this method in my `views.py` for the urls I needed but that seems to be maintenance nightmare

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could implement a middleware that would check a user against the url except the whitelist:

```
class MyAuthMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        if request.path in self.whitelist:
            return
        # Do the user checking otherwise
```